# how to make jquery transition smoothly

Tags: jquery, css

I already looked up other people's questions about this jquery transition executing smoothly, and found out that it can be done like the following.

```
<img src="images/header_type1.png" 
     onclick="jQuery('.xe-clearfix').addClass('menu_type_1',200),
              jQuery('.xe-clearfix').removeClass('menu_type_3',200)">
```

so that if i click the image, the transition insdie class can happen smoothly.

but my question is how do you apply the same thing to the display:none and display: block?

I set up the toggleclass to see if it works, but it stutters.

(you can go to my website and click on the cog button on the leftside)
http://xestudio.xco.kr/ (you will need to disable your chrome extension adblock or ublock, i assure you it's a safe webpage)

And this is the code

```
jQuery('.cmn-toggle').on('click',function(){
jQuery('.fluid_container').toggleClass('hide',200);
jQuery('.gnb>ul>li>a').toggleClass('on',200);
jQuery('.logo_text').toggleClass('on',200);
jQuery('.xe-clearfix').toggleClass('on',200);
jQuery('.active').toggleClass('on',200);

});
```

here's CSS

```
    .fluid_container {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height:400px;
}
    .fluid_container.hide {
        display: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height:400px;

}
```

Also, you can see the panel on the left has slider that you can move it around to adjust the width of the body, and im trying to apply that same transitioning effect to this as well.

is there any difference if i put 200 value or not?

here is the code

```
(function($) {
var $width = $('#slider_body_width');
var $sample= $('body');
var $samples= $('.shrink .header');

$width.on('input', function() {
$sample.width($width.val()+"%");
$samples.width($width.val()+"%"); 
$('body').css('margin','0 auto');  
});
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks.

---

Added.

To slove the problem, I did it rather like this

```
.fluid_container {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.fluid_container.hide {
height: 0;
}
```

but the problem is that, once i click the toggle button,
there's an empty space in replacement of the slider that's been hidden.

anyone know what's causing this?

Comment: in CSS add display:none to remove empty space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can directly use show or hide instead of toggleClass. For example

```
$('.fluid_container').hide(300);
```

the above code makesure your container will be hidden in 300 milli second

Comment: good idea. but that's not feasible because once it hiddens itself it doesn't show up anymore. i need toggle function,

Answer (score 0):

I would use opacity and transition in css, and just toggle class in the scripts.

```
//js
jQuery('.fluid_container').toggleClass('hide');

//css
.fluid_container {
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.fluid_container.hide {
    opacity: 0;
}
```